# Hibernate persistent context is maintaing old entity state

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

In order to understand how persistence context works, i tried the following scenario. But somehow hibernate was maintaining older entity state even after update was successful in its persistence context

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="payments")
public class Payment {
  
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="account_id")
  private Long accountId;

  private BigDecimal amount;

  private Boolean deleted;

}
```

**ServiceA**

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class ServiceA{

  @Autowired
  private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void testServiceA(Long accountId, Long paymentId){
    Payment payment = paymentRepository.findByAccountAndIdAndDeletedIsFalse(
        accountId,
        paymentId
    );
    payment.setAmount(BigDecimal.ONE);

    paymentRepository.save(payment);
  }

}
```

**ServiceB**

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class ServiceB{

  @Autowired
  private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA serviceA;

  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void testServiceB(Long accountId, Long paymentId){
    Payment payment = paymentRepository.findByAccountAndIdAndDeletedIsFalse(
        accountId,
        paymentId
    );
    serviceA.testServiceA(accountId, paymentId);
  }

}
```

**ServiceC**

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class ServiceC{

  @Autowired
  private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void testServiceC(Long accountId, Long paymentId){
    Payment payment = paymentRepository.findByAccountAndIdAndDeletedIsFalse(
        accountId,
        paymentId
    );
    log.info("testing service C: payment value is {}", payment.getAmount());
  }

}
```

**ServiceD**

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class ServiceD{

  @Autowired
  private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceC serviceC;

  public void testServiceD() throws PaymentNotFoundException {
    Long paymentId = 1L;
    Long accountId = 1L;

    serviceB.testServiceB(accountId, paymentId);
    serviceC.testServiceC(accountId, paymentId);

    Payment payment = paymentRepository.findByAccountAndIdAndDeletedIsFalse(
        accountId,
        paymentId
    );

    log.info("testing service D: payment value is {}", payment.getAmount());
  }

}
```

**Controller**

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
  public void test(){
    serviceD.testServiceD();
  }
```

**Given a payment already exist with id 1 and account 1, with amount 50.**

**Expectation**
As testServiceD method is not running under any transaction and testServiceC is running in a new transaction always, i was expecting the logs will print the updated amount of the payment.

But when I ran the above code following logs got printed

```
testing service C: payment value is 50
testing service D: payment value is 50
```

Basically, we are seeing the amount getting printed before update

**How i resolved it**

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class ServiceD{

  @Autowired
  private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceC serviceC;

  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public void testServiceD() throws PaymentNotFoundException {
    Long paymentId = 1L;
    Long accountId = 1L;

    serviceB.testServiceB(accountId, paymentId);
    // clear cache
    entityManager.clear();
    serviceC.testServiceC(accountId, paymentId);

    Payment payment = paymentRepository.findByAccountAndIdAndDeletedIsFalse(
        accountId,
        paymentId
    );

    log.info("testing service D: payment value is {}", payment.getAmount());
  }

}
```

Now when i run the code , following logs are printed
(Again given payment amount is 50)

```
testing service C: payment value is 1
testing service D: payment value is 1
```

Comment: `entityManager.clear();` - the body of test method reveals you somehow was able to acquire live instance of EM, that definitely means there is another transaction (EM) which somehow participate in test scenario

Comment: Actually I @Autowired EntityManager in ServiceD.

Comment: In each Service class you can start by printing the value of  `payment` after executing `.findByAccountAndIdAndDeletedIsFalse` . In ServiceA after `payment.setAmount()` you can also print the value of `payment` again to see new values first. Do you have to precisely use all those services to update record or you are open to alternative way to perform updates?